# as chief ideologist - article omissiom

Tags: grammar

Source: http://www.csmonitor.com/World/Europe/2014/0707/With-Ukraine-rebels-on-the-ropes-some-Russians-ask-Where-is-Putin-video

> Dugin is widely viewed **as chief ideologist** for the hawkish wing of Russia's ruling elite, and his persistent influence inside the Kremlin has been widely documented.

Why is there no definite nor indefinite article in front of **chief ideologist** to denote that he is either just one of many chief ideologists, if there are more than one of them (indefinite article), or *the* to denote that he is the one and only chief in charge (definite article)?

Comment: "Chief ideologist" will do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "the" before chief ideologist is not required. Using "the" would add some emphasis to it. The qualifier "chief" implies there is only one chief ideologist. Saying "a chief ideologist for the hawkish wing..." in this context would imply that there are multiple chief ideologists but would make the expression ambiguous.